# Node Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, express, callback, node-async, node-request

I have not found a question with a similar setup... how do I fix this?

I'm using node, express routing, request to call a token from an api, and async series to keep everything clean. I simplified the code by only showing one function in the async series.

routes.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var isAuthenticated = require("./passportAuth.js")
var tokens = require('./tokens')

module.exports = function() {
  router.get('/allTokens', isAuthenticated, tokens())
  return router
}
```

./tokens.js

```
var request = require("request")
var async = require('async')

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  var allTokens = function(callback) {
    request('url', function(err, res, body) {
      if(err) return callback(err, null)
      return callback(null, 'success')
    })
  }

  var asyncFinally = function(err, results) {
    if(err) return next(err)
    res.send(results)
  }

  async.series([allTokens], asyncFinally)
}
```

Error message

```
Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router is expecting a function value but you are passing in an invoked function tokens().  Try just tokens.

Comment: Solved.  Wow!  That easy huh.  Thank you very much, I was completely puzzled why it was not working as is.

Answer (score 1):

You are prematurely calling the `tokens()` function rather than just passing a reference to it.  Change this:

```
router.get('/allTokens', isAuthenticated, tokens())
```

to this:

```
router.get('/allTokens', isAuthenticated, tokens)
```

Remember that any time you put `()` after a function name that means to call it now (immediately).  Any time you just pass the function name by itself, that just passes a reference to the function that can be called later at the appropriate time (that's what you want here).  This is a very common mistake.

Since calling `tokens()` returns `undefined`, that is what you end up passing to `router.get()` and thus why you get the specific error message you see.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, you are absolutely right and it worked!